# The difference between "gern Deutsche" and Deutsche gern

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, emphasis

Is there any difference between the meaning/emphasis of the following sentences?:

> Lerne ihr gern Deutsche?

> Lerne ihr Deutsche gern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct sentences are

> Lernt ihr gern Deutsch?

and

> Lernt ihr Deutsch gern?

Both word orders are correct, and the difference in meaning is small. It is basically a small difference in emphasis on the word that comes earlier.